# Yosemite - Screen saver options - no default showing

Tags: macos, screensaver

After updating to Yosemite I have no screen saver default showings at all.
How can I add photos?  When I click screen saver options the only thing that shows up to choose is thickness color and speed.
How can I change this to add my photos?

Answer (score 1):

Choose a Style on the left, then choose a source from the drop menu in the centre...

[image]

Thickness, Colour & Speed sounds like the setup options for Flurry...

[image]